# Personalized URLs in ASP.Net Information Request

Tags: .net, asp.net, url, dns

I've done a lot of searching trying to figure this out: I am soon to develop an app using Personalized URLs in ASP .Net. Thankfully we are going to use the mysite.com/user1, mysite.com/user2 approach, as I can find plenty of info on making that happen using URL rewrites.

However, in the post @ http://forums.asp.net/p/1259856/2842613.aspx#2842613 there is someone asking if there is a way to do something along the lines of user1.mysite.com, but dynamically. In the post there are answers that it can be done, but they are not very clear. I presented this my supervisor who then asked how does this work with DNS and I shrugged my shoulders and did the Scooby-Doo "I don't know" sound (rye-ron't-row)...

Does anybody have any insight on this? I've spent the weekend searching for something so the next time one of these questions popup, I can be prepared...

Comment: Are you trying to solve a problem, or just keep your job? :)

Comment: this sounds like it belongs at http://serverfault.com/

Comment: No, this is a new idea coming down the pipe...I've done some research but was looking to see what I could dig up beforehand...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the DNS side you either need to enter each subdomain manually or use a [wildcard DNS entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_DNS_record).

Comment: Thank you...I was looking for a problematically way of doing it in .Net versus going all server admin...    I thought I left those days behind me.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

... and then the Webserver part you need to have an empty HostHeader so the website receives all requests on the given IP.